# WFFM - Rule Set Editor - Active Directory Federated Identity

Tags: wffm, rules-engine

I am trying to create a rule for a WFFM email address field to populate the field with the logged in users email address. But, I am not sure what rule to use or if any of the rules will work at all for the way we have our security set-up.

We are using Active Directory Federated Identity for the log in process.

Here is some sample C# code that sets the logged in user's email address to a UserSession class:

**Base Session Class:**

```
public abstract class BaseSession 
{
    protected static bool ContainsKey(String paramName) {
    bool res = false;
    try {
             if (HttpContext.Current.Session[paramName] != null)
                res = true;
        }
        catch { res = false; }
    return res;
}
```

**User Session Class:**

```
public class UserSession : BaseSession
{
    public static string EmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            if (ContainsKey(RootItems.Keys.EmailAddress))
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[RootItems.Keys.EmailAddress] as string;
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[RootItems.Keys.EmailAddress] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Setting the Email Address to the UserSession Class:**

```
using System.IdentityModel.Services;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Claims;

SessionSecurityToken sessionToken = null;
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(out sessionToken);
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken(sessionToken, true);
ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = sessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal;

foreach (var varClaims in claimsPrincipal.Claims)
{
    if (varClaims.Type.Contains("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"))
        UserSession.EmailAddress = varClaims.Value;
}
```

**Not Sure Which Security Rule to Choose:**

[image]